# Computing the decomposition of a representation of $S_n$

Tags: linear-algebra, representation-theory, computational-mathematics, computer-algebra-systems

I have an explicitly defined representation of the symmetric group that I would like to decompose into irreducibles. How to do this most easily?

The best approach I have so far is as follows:

Find a set of generators of $S_n$, eg. $(12)$ and $(123...n)$ and find the common invariant subspaces of their corresponding matrices. To find the common invariant subspaces of two matrices, find their individual eigendecompositions and 'merge' them.

This approach is not very good since computing the eigendecomposition is messy (it can't easily be done exactly with a computer) and should also not be necessary since I know all irreducible representations are rational.

I'm interested in either a better approach or a way to make the current approach useful. I really do want the coordinates of the invariant subspaces out, and as input I have the matrices for all group elements.

Comment: You *can* compute the eigenvalues exactly because they're all in the field $\mathbb Q\left(\zeta_1,\zeta_2,...,\zeta_n\right)$ with $\zeta_i$ being a primitive $i$-th root of unity and because in fields like this it is possible to do precise computations (don't ask me how, but systems like Sage can do it). But I'm not sure whether the common invariant subspaces of two generators help you very much in decomposing the representation.

Comment: One thing you can do is taking the images of the actions of the primitive central idempotents of $\mathbb Q\left[S_n\right]$ on your representations. This yields not the irreducible addends, but the isotypic components (i. e., the sums of all irreducible addends corresponding to partition $\lambda$ for all partitions $\lambda$ of $n$). So you have these isotypic components, each corresponding to a partition $\lambda$, and you have to further split them into irreducibles. On the isotypic component corresponding to partition $\lambda$, the group algebra $\mathbb Q\left[S_n\right]$ acts ...

Comment: ... via a certain addend in its Artin-Wedderburn decomposition, which is isomorphic to a matrix ring over $\mathbb Q$. Via Young's seminormal form, you can explicitly describe such an isomorphism, and explicitly write the elementary matrices (i. e., the matrices having only one $1$ and otherwise only $0$'s in their cells) of this matrix ring as elements of $\mathbb Q\left[S_n\right]$ (in as far as a recursive definition can be considered explicit). Letting each of these elementary matrices act on your representation then gives you an irreducible addend or $0$. Warning: ...

Comment: ... Some of the irreducible addends you get this way might be identical or otherwise "overlap" (in the sense that, e. g., the span of three of them is spanned by two already). I don't know if this can actually happen but I can't rule it out. Of course, this is just a theoretical answer, and there are probably some better algorithms around.